# r convert an r function with an embedded function into Rcpp

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I have an R function that has two R functions embedded in it.

The structure is something like this:

- `f2` is the function to optimize over and
- `optimize` is a base R function that runs `f2` multiple times until it finds a minimum between 1 and 5 or ends up at an edge.

The embedding structure in R means that `a` is calculated once and read into `optimize`.

I can convert `f1` and `f2` to Rcpp functions and import the optimize function into Rcpp.

But when I put the `cpp` version of `f2` inside the Rcpp version of `f1`, I get an error message that this type of embedding is not allowed.

I realize this is not a reproducible example. I couldn't figure out how to search for this type of construction in stack overflow so I'm looking for tips on how to find the right way to do this.

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z) {
     a <- x + y
     b <- x + b
     f2 <- function(z) {
         d <- z + a + b
     }
     out <- optimize(f2, c(1, 5))
     return(out)
}
```

Comment: What I don't get: In your example you give, `f2` is defined as an R function. - Why not giving the `cpp` code of `f2` separately and use `f2` exactly as you use in your code? That would help others to recreate the problem.

Comment: Are you running the R functions `f1` and `f2` from C++ code?  Or did you translate `f1` and `f2` into C++ code?

Comment: "and import the optimize function into Rcpp." Don't do that. That will actually be less efficient than using `optimize` at R level. It makes sense to implement `f2` in Rcpp (if it actually does something time consuming). You could also split `f1` in two functions and implement the parts before the `optimize` call in Rcpp (if those were actally time consuming). But avoid using R functions in Rcpp.

Comment: I haven't included the cpp code because at the moment it's got extraneous material. I have translated f1 and f2 into C++ code. I will be running the final code over daily climate/weather data from 5 different earth system models for 60 years so speed is a key consideration. Leaving optimize in an R function is definitely a consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see from your code is that `f2` is a closure (it uses `a` and `b`, but it doesn't have them in the arguments list).
The supposed reason is - I guess - because you thought `optimize` needs a monadic function (a function with just one argument) to `optimize` over. But that is not true.

Look [here in the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optimize):

> optimize(f, interval, …, lower = min(interval), upper = max(interval),
> maximum = FALSE,
> tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25)

> optimise(f, interval, …, lower = min(interval), upper = max(interval),
> maximum = FALSE,
> tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25)

with:

```
f                  the function to be optimized. 
                   The function is either minimized or maximized over 
                   its first argument depending on the value of maximum.
interval           a vector containing the end-points of the interval to be searched for the minimum.
…                  additional named or unnamed arguments to be passed to f.
lower              the lower end point of the interval to be searched.
upper              the upper end point of the interval to be searched.
maximum            logical. Should we maximize or minimize (the default)?
tol                the desired accuracy.
```

So you can give `a` and `b` after the `interval` as arguments.

The solution is:

```
f2 <- function(z, a, b) {
     d <- z + a + b
     return(d)
}


f1 <- function(x, y, z) {
     a <- x + y
     b <- x + b
     out <- optimize(f2, c(1, 5), a, b)
     return(out)
}
```

But in `Rcpp` ;) .